# Exist $a,b$ such that $-1<a<0<b<1$ and satisfy $|P(a)| \geq 1$, $P(b) \geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, polynomials

> **Problem**: Let $n\geq 2$ be an even integer. Consider a monic polynomial $P(x)$ ($\deg P=n$) with real coefficients which has $n$ real roots $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ (no need to be distinct) and $-1\leq x_i \leq 1$ for all $i=1,2,...,n$.
> $\phantom{2}$
> Prove that there doesn't exist two real numbers $a,b$ such that $-1<a<0<b<1$ and satisfy $|P(a)|\geq 1$ and $P(b)\geq 1$.

**My attempt**:
My work so far is just prove that the statement is true for $n=2$. For general, i've checked for $n=4,6$ with some unique polynomials and it's true. But i've not done for $n=4,6$ and no idea for general case*

Someone can help me with this problem ? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you state your work for $n=2$? That will show us what you know, and it might be able to generalize from there. $\quad$ For $n=4, 6$, do you mean "some unique **polynomial**"? Likewise, please show your work.

Comment: no, my work for $n=2$ cant be able to general. I calculated $P(-1),P(1)$ and $P(root-of-P'(x))$ then case bash. If apllying that way to general, we must try to do st with root of $P'(x)$, what i think is impossible when $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: yes, 'some unique polynomial'

Comment: Can you write out your proof for $n=2$? You can essentially induct your way from there.

Comment: thank, i'll try

Comment: @Calvin Note that $|P(a)P(b)|$ can be as large as $2^{2n}-\epsilon$ for some $P$ as above and some $-1<a<0, 0<b<1$ if all the roots are completely skewed towards $1$ or all towards $-1$; $|P(a)P(b)|<1$ holds if half the roots are negative and half are positive, as well as in some less symmetric cases but where the roots on the side where are more, are distributed around and not bunched together

Comment: Yes, my approach is incorrect. Came to that same conclusion.

Comment: @Calvin A more "unitary" solution would be interesting - the main point is that $1+x$ cannot be that big when $0 < x \le 1$ but $1-x$ can be very small and of course their product is always less than $1$, so I thought of a geometric way of expressing that, but couldn't see it; also symmetrizing the problem by looking at $Q(x)=P(-x)$ and noting that $|P(x)Q(x)|<1, 0<|x|<1$ may lead somewhere, but again couldn't find a way with that

Answer (score 3):

Let's number the roots so $x_1=z_1,..x_k=z_k \ge 0$ and $y_1=-x_{k+1},...y_{2n-k}=-x_{2n} \ge 0$, where $0 \le k \le 2n$ (if $k=0$ or $k=2n$ the corresponding set is empty).

Assume there is $-1<a<0, 0<b<1$ st $|P(a)| \ge 1, |P(b)| \ge 1$ (which clearly implies that $0<k<2n$ since the roots cannot be all negative or all non-negative by the assumption above)

$|P(a)P(b)|=\Pi_{1 \le r \le k, 1 \le q \le 2n-k}(|a|+z_r)|(b-z_r)|(|a|-y_q)|(b+y_q)$, so using the mean inequality we get:

$4n|P(a)P(b)|^{4n} \le \sum (|a|+z_r)+(b+y_q)+|b-z_r|+||a|-y_q|=l|a|+mb+\sum c_rz_r+\sum d_qy_q=S$,

where $l+m+\sum c_r+\sum d_q=4n$ since when we resolve the absolute values the sum of the coefficients is zero, while the sum of the coefficients in the sums is just $2k+2(2n-k)=4n$ as $r$ takes $k$ values and $q$ takes $2n-k$ values (note that by assumption $P(a)P(b) \ne 0$ so $a,b$ are not roots, hence the absolute values are unambiguously resolved)

Note that $c_r,d_q$ are either $0$ or $2$ while $l \ge 2k-2n, m \ge 2n-2k$ so one of $l,m >0$ unless $k=n$

Now if $l, m \ge 0$ then since $0 \le z_r, y_q \le 1$ and $0<|a|,b<1$, we get $S < l+m+\sum c_r +\sum d_q < 4n$ unless $l=m=0$ (hence $k=n$ as above) and then again $S<4n$ unless $z_r=y_q=1$ which implies $P(x)=(1-x^2)^n$ for which $|P(a)|, |P(b)|<1$ contradiction.

Otherwise $S<4n$ in this case, so $|P(a)P(b)|<1$ Contradiction again!

Now assume one of $l,m <0$ and wlog we can assume $m<0$ hence $k>n$ so there are at least $2n-k+1$'s $z_r$'s where $|b-z_r|=z_r-b$, hence numbering $2n-k$ of those as $w_1,..w_{2n-k}$ we note that $P(b)=Q(b)\Pi_{q=1,2n-k}(b-w_q)(b+y_q)$ with $|Q(b)| <1$ as it consists only of factors $b-z_r$ which are in $(-1,1)$ and there is at least one such since $k>n$

But now we have that $0<b<w_q$ for all $q=1,..2n-k$ and the quadratic $A(x)=(w_q-x)(x+y_q)$ assumes its absolute value maximum on $[0,w-q]$ either at its ends or at $\frac{y_q-w_q}{2}$ (if it's in the interval which means $w_q \le y_q \le 3w_q$) and $|A(0)| \le 1, A(w_q)=0, |A(\frac{y_q-w_q}{2})| =\frac{3w_q-y_q}{2} \frac{3y_q-w_q}{2} \le ((w_q+y_q)/2)^2 \le 1$ by the mean inequality, so in any case each product $|(w_q-b)(b+y_q)| \le 1$ and combined with $|Q(b)|<1$ gives $|P(b)|<1$ and we get a contradiction in this case again!

Comment: great work, mr Conrad !